# see Unix userids in macOS

Tags: macos, unix, shell, user-accounts, etcpasswd

I have a million-file 900-userid snapshot of an old Unix file server.  On Linux I can browse it and have `ls -l` show usernames from the snapshot's `/etc/passwd`, by just chroot'ing to the snapshot's top directory.

I've copied this snapshot to an exFAT-formatted USB drive, to mail to a Mac user.  But in macOS my chroot trick might fail to show usernames, because those come from DirectoryService instead of /etc/passwd.
(He won't add 900 users to his Mac, nor will he install Linux on it.)

How can he view these usernames in file listings?

Or will he have to pipe `ls -ln` through a custom script that replaces uid/gid's with the names in that password file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may find `tar` useful. I tested GNU `tar` on Debian and Ubuntu. I have no access to Mac, its `tar` may not be so reach with options. Still I think you will be able to get some ideas from my answer.

`tar -xf archive.tar mountpoint/` will store file owners/groups primarily as character strings, unless you use `--numeric-owner`. There are few other options you certainly *don't* want to use, e.g. `--owner=`.

On the target system extracting the archive may mangle the ownership information and it will in your case. *But* you can view the original users/groups with

```
tar -tvf archive.tar
```

or e.g.

```
tar -tvf archive.tar path/to/object1/within/archive path/to/object2
```

---

If the large snapshot has already been sent and you don't want to send another large file, the other user may try to build `archive.tar` using `--owner-map=` to connect numeric UIDs from the snapshot to arbitrary names provided by you (or by the `/etc/passwd` of the snapshot). It requires some effort to build a map file. I'm also afraid this won't work with groups.

In this case copy the metadata only (on your system):

```
cp -a --attributes-only mountpoint/ whatever
```

and `tar` the resulting empty files:

```
tar -xf metadata.tar whatever/
```

Send `metadata.tar` to the other user (`gzip` it maybe to reduce size). To view ownership information they should run `tar -tvf metadata.tar`.

Comment: `--owner-map` needs GNU tar 1.3+, https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_33.html#SEC69.  On macOS, on 10.6+ use `gnutar`, else `brew install gnu-tar`.